# seperate comma seperated string values in string variable

Tags: javascript

I am trying to extract the string which is like

```
var str = "[\"/home/dev/servers\", \"e334ffssfds245fsdff2f\"]"
```

Desired ouput

```
a = "/home/dev/servers"
b = "e334ffssfds245fsdff2f"
```

Comment: Invalid `str`. `"` should be after `]`

Comment: Is it allways like that ?

Comment: So why is it not just an array to start? Issue here is the string is flawed from the start, all of those slashed need to be doubled up `[\"\\home\\dev\\servers\",...`

Comment: So will the format always be the same? and have you tried `str.split(',')`?

Comment: @Moad Ennagi it does not in my System. Are you sure?

Comment: OP changed the string, you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are:

```js
const str = "[\"/home/dev/servers\", \"e334ffssfds245fsdff2f\"]";

const object = JSON.parse(str);

const a = object[0];
const b = object[1];

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Comment: I am getting **Argument of type '_Blob' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'Buffer' is not assignable to type 'string'.**

Answer (score 2):

The following will work fine for you.

```
var str = "[\"/home/dev/servers\", \"e334ffssfds245fsdff2f\"]";

var foo = JSON.parse(str); //Parse the JSON into an object.

var a = foo[0];
var b = foo[1];
```

Comment: I just changed the code, could you please check it again

Comment: This will not output OP expected results.

Comment: Updated answer to reflect OP's changes.

Comment: I am getting **Argument of type '_Blob' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'Buffer' is not assignable to type 'string'. **

Comment: @BhargavTeja that error is unrelated to this question, or the code that is creating that error has not been posted in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Using `JSON.parse()`

```js
let [a, b] = JSON.parse("[\"/home/dev/servers\", \"e334ffssfds245fsdff2f\"]")

console.log(a)
console.log(b)
```